# shareReplay + clear buffered events

Tags: rxjs

Hi there I need a variant of `shareReplay()` that cache events until I trigger a signal asking it to discard buffered events.

Is there an operator or a combination of operators that let me do that easily or should I build my own custom operator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the following code, `switchMap` can cancel the stream subscription and resubscribe which means `shareReplay()` will be a fresh one

```
const intercept = fromEvent(document, "click").pipe(startWith(true))
const cacheEvent=interval(2000).pipe(shareReplay(1))
const source = intercept.pipe(switchMapTo(cacheEvent))
```